# Поиск максимальной пары чисел при условии, что числа находятся на определенном интервале

Tags: python

готовлюсь к экзаменам и при подготовке возникла сложность с одним типом задач.
На вход программы подаются результаты измерений, выполняемых прибором с интервалом 1 минуту. Все данные – целые числа (возможно, отрицательные). Требуется найти наибольшую сумму двух результатов измерений, выполненных с интервалом не менее, чем в 7 минут. Количество элементов последовательности не превышает 10000.
Пытался решить задачу с помощью массива, однако в данном случае получается перебор, и программа не эффективна по времени и памяти. Однако можно решить задачу без вложенных циклов, благодаря чему время работы программы будет увеличиваться линейно.
Можно создать массив на 7 элементов и запустить ввод элементов от 1 до 7.
Фрагмент кода:

```
d=7
a=[0]*d
n=int(input())
for i in range (d):
    a[i]=int(input())
```

После чего мы запускаем новый цикл (for i in range(d, n):), в котором начинаем вводить новые числа, и на этом у меня возникли затруднения. Мы получаем i, находим остаток отделения от него и используем его как индекс к массиву, после чего находим сумму, приравниваем ее к максимум, и дальше, добавляя стандартный алгоритм поиска максимума, находим максимальную пару.Однако здесь будет ошибка, которую я не пойму как убрать. Я сравниваю пары чисел которые могут быть только на одном интервале(7), однако максимумом могут быть и числа на интервале 8,9,10. Был бы очень сильно благодарен, если бы помогли хотя бы алгоритмом решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Задача сформулировано очень сумбурно. Но если читать дословно, что вы написали, то надо в результате показать сумму двух чисел, отстоящих друг от друга более чем на 7 тактов измерения. При этом номера тактов нас не спрашивают.

При этом данные поступают динамически,т.е. мы обязаны обрабатывать по одному числу и не можем "заглянуть вперед", т.е. обрабатывая данные на 10-м такте, мы не знаем что будет дальше.

Предположим, мы находимся на 8-й минуте. Это значит, что единственный кандидат на "наибольшую сумму" есть сумма значения на первой минуте плюс значение 8-й минуты. Запомнили. Перешли к 9-й минуте. Нам надо взять максимальное значение за 1-ю и 2-ю минуты, прибавить к значению за 9-ю минуту и сравнить с предыдущим значением "наибольшей суммы". И соответственно, либо изменить "наибольшую сумму" либо нет. Перешли к 10-й минуте. Теперь мы должны взять максимальное значение за 1-ю,2-ю и 3-ю минуты, прибавить к нему значение за 10-ю минуту и снова сравнить с текущим "наибольшей суммой".

Надеюсь, вы уловили смысл. Вновь пришедшее значение сравнивается с максимальным значением всех точек, отстоящих от нее на 7 и более позиций вниз и если эта сумма больше текущей "наибольшей суммы", то последняя изменяется. По окончанию прохода (достижения последней точки) в переменной "наибольшая сумма" окажется именно нужная вам сумма двух чисел.

Немного запутано. Специально покажу на более коротком примере. И специально не ввожу динамически числа, и использую готовый массив -  в реале, естественно надо a[i]читать из входного потока. По крайней мере, можно визуально проверить, что все работает правильно

```
a=[7,25,12,-10,-16,3,28,46,-17,34,65,20,10,0,-10,8,70,12,25,4]
cur_max_sum=0
for i in range (7,len(a)):
    #a[i]=int(input())  --- изменить в реальной задаче
    if a[i]+max(a[0:i-6]) > cur_max_sum:
        cur_max_sum=a[i]+max(a[0:i-6])
        print (a[i],cur_max_sum)
```

Контрольный вывод:

```
46 53
34 59
65 90
70 116
```

Последняя строчка показывает, что максимальная сумма, удовлетворяющая вашему условию - 116,  получена она при поступлении точки со значением 70, и больше превышена не была.

Еще пример. Если я поменяю местами два числа, составляющих максимальную сумму местами

```
a=[7,25,12,-10,-16,3,28,70,-17,34,65,20,10,0,-10,8,46,12,25,4]
```

то контрольный вывод примет вид:

```
70 77
65 90
46 116
```

что естественно, так как сумма не изменилась, а вот обнаружили мы ее при присмотре теперь уже значения 46.

Если бы в задаче требовалось выдать номера точек, составляющих это "наибольшую сумму", тогда вам бы пришлось усложнить алгоритм. Но зато вместо постоянного поиска максимума вы можете на первом шаге положить индекс "текущего максимального элемента" равным нулю, а потом просто менять его или нет в зависимости от того больше-ли a[i-6] этого "текущего максимума" или нет. Другими словами, вы всегда будете знать максимальный элемент в начальном срезе массива и его индекс. И a[i] сравнивать именно с этим значением. Думаю, что при этом объем вычислительной работы должен еще и уменьшиться в итоге.